# How can I see that the rank of $\mathrm{SU}(N)$ is $N-1$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Is there a way to understand intuitively why this must be the case? Or is there a kind of easy-to-see proof of this result? Thank you in advance.

Comment: does this answer your question?   (Lie algebra structure) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#Lie_algebra_structure

Comment: I assume you're comfortable with the fact that diagonal matrices $U(1)^n \subset U(n)$ are a maximal torus. Note that the determinant map is non-trivial on this group, with kernel isomorphic to $U(1)^{n-1}$. Therefore there is a subgroup of $SU(n)$ isomorphic to $U(1)^{n-1}$. There can be no subgroup of $SU(n)$ isomorphic to $U(1)^n$, because the map $\det: T \to U(1)$ is non-trivial on any maximal torus in $U(n)$ (which follows from the fact that all maximal tori are conjugate).

Comment: @MikeMiller, how does the non-triviality of the determinant on a torus in $\operatorname U(n)$ imply that $\operatorname{SU}(n)$ cannot have a subgroup isomorphic to $\operatorname U(1)^n$?  (I believe it does, I just don't see it.)  For what it's worth, I would argue that $\ker(\operatorname U(1)^n \to \operatorname U(1))$ is a torus, hence *contained in* a maximal torus in $\operatorname{SU}(n)$; but it's self centralising in $\operatorname{SU}(n)$, hence already maximal.

Comment: @LSpice Include that subgroup into $U(n)$; since determinant is trivial on $SU(n)$ it's also trivial on this subgroup. (Since an arbitrary n-dimensional torus in $U(n)$ is conjugate to the standard one, and the standard one has non-trivial determinant, and triviality of the determinant map is conjugation-invariant, we get a contradiction.) Your argument is more straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

It seems easier to work on the level of the Lie algebras, the tangent to a maximal torus being precisely a maximal abelian subalgebra. The Lie algebra of $SU(n)$ is $n\times n$ traceless skew-Hermitian matrices. If they commute, they are simultaneously diagonalizable (by a version of spectral theorem), so in some basis are diagonal. That means (recalling the traceless condition) that the dimension is at most $n-1$. Of course it is then exactly $n-1$.

Comment: For "precisely a maximal abelian subalgebra" we are using that the group is compact. For more general semisimple Lie algebras, the correct Lie algebra analogue of a maximal torus is a [Cartan subalgebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_subalgebra), which in the non-compact case is not necessarily the same as a maximal abelian subalgebra. (I'm sure you know all this, I point it out for the sake of the OP.)

Comment: Since we refer at the end to the existence of a known ($n - 1$)-dimensional CSA $\mathfrak h$ anyway, it seems that we might as well avoid any heavy machinery:  simply observe that $\mathfrak h$ is Abelian and (by calculation, say) that it is self centralising in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$, hence that it is maximal Abelian.  (This is just the Lie-algebra version of my group [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953207/how-can-i-see-that-the-rank-of-sun-is-n-1#comment8151685_3953207).)

Comment: @LSpice Sure. I think it depends on what you prefer -- a calculation or a reference to a known result. BTW, perhaps you should add your approach as a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

$\DeclareMathOperator\U{U}\DeclareMathOperator\diag{diag}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\Cent{C}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Per @Max's [suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953207/how-can-i-see-that-the-rank-of-sun-is-n-1/3953258#comment8154119_3953258), I add an approach very similar to theirs, but where things boil down slightly differently in the end.

It is clear that $T = \ker(\det : \U(1)^n \to \U(1))$ is an $(n - 1)$-dimensional torus.  (Explicitly, the isomorphism with $\U(1)^{n - 1}$ is given by $(z_1, \dotsc, z_n) \mapsto (z_1, \dotsc, z_{n - 1})$.)  It is straightforward to show that $\Cent_{\SU(n)}(T) = T$, but I'll put an explanation in the next paragraph anyway.  Granted this, we know that a maximal torus in $\SU(n)$ containing $T$ must be contained in $\Cent_{\SU(n)}(T) = T$, hence equal $T$, so that some (hence every, because they are all conjugate) maximal torus is ($n - 1$)-dimensional.

Now to show that $\Cent_{\SU(n)}(T) = T$.  I'll show more generally (since $T$ is the group of diagonal matrices in $\SU(n)$) that $\Cent_{\GL(n)}(T)$ consists of diagonal matrices.  In fact, even $\Cent_{\GL(n)}(t)$ consists of diagonal matrices for any *single* diagonal matrix $t = \diag(z_1, \dotsc, z_n)$ where the $z_i$ are all different and all have norm $1$.  (By working with the full torus rather than just a single element, this argument can be made to work even over fields that don't have enough scalars to produce such a diagonal matrix … except, as an MO [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/424453) reminded me, in the extremely small case of $\mathbb F_2$.)  If $g$ commutes with $t$ and $i \ne j$, then the $(i, j)$ entry of $g t$ is $g_{i j}z_j$, but the $(i, j)$ entry of $t g$ is $z_i g_{i j}$, and the fact that these are equal (since $g t = t g$) but that $z_i \ne z_j$ implies that $g_{i j}$ is $0$.